# Best practice for solr faceting? numeric or strings

Tags: solr

What is the best practice for faceting? numeric or string?

I need a field in solr for faceting and do some filter on this facet query.

Now I have two solutions combine values to a string "34-45-2345" or a fixed length integer "0034004502345" (0034|0045|02345). But which one is better and smaller at indexing?

Comment: They should generally be the same; a token (which is what you're faceting over) is generally a string regardless. So just use a delimiter symbol, and if you're running into issues later, optimize it if necessary. You probably won't need to do anything.